# Variable value does not change why?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code:

```
var popupFirstName;
PopupFirstNameButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    popupFirstName = 'SomeValue';
});
```

When I `alert(popupFirstName)` in some other function it says `undefined`. How can I get the value?

Comment: I assume it's because `popupFirstName` is a local variable, rather than the global you're using it as, but without more code it's hard to say. Can we see the rest of the related JavaScript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`popupFirstName` has a scope local to where it is placed, which we don't know from what you've told us. But I imagine it is in a function, so the scope will be local to that function. The function you've defined inherits access to that variable; this is a convenience feature of the language.

If you'd like to make a single instance of the variable that has global scope, write `window.popupFirstName`.

Answer (score 1):

In which browser are you testing? Firefox needs a third parameter for [**`addEventListener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and IE uses a completely different method ([**`attachEvent`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

You can try to assign the function to `onclick`:

```
PopupFirstNameButton.onclick = function(){
    popupFirstName = 'SomeValue';
};
```

If you want to learn more about advanced event handling and its cross browser issues, or about JavaScript and events in general, I suggest to read the good [articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

It goes without saying that the button has to be clicked before the variable is set and that the function where you call `alert(popupFirstName)` has to have access to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

make sure this variable is declared in the same block scope as the function calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the third argument for the addEventListener function. For Firefox for example, you would need:

```
PopupFirstNameButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    popupFirstName = 'SomeValue';
}, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener